# Why can layer filter not be null or undefined when using mapbox GL setStyle?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

When I use setStyle and a layer has filter of null or undefined, this raises errors. Although according to the style spec filter is optional, and setFilter can take null or undefined https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#setfilter it does raise errors.

So how can I reset a filter on a layer then?

```
Error: layers[1].filter: array expected, null found
    at Function.module.exports.emitErrors (mapbox-gl.js:402)
    at t.setState (mapbox-gl.js:376)
    at e.setStyle (mapbox-gl.js:474)
```

Comment: As a workaround, you can always just make a nonsense filter: `map.setFilter(mylayer, ['!=', 'Z','X'])`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by removing the filter prop from the layer object altogether, that successfully clears the filter

```
const { filter, ...newProps } = state.layers[i];
new_layers.push(newProps);
```

Comment: You could also use the `delete()` function.